# Rewriting PHP Query to HTML using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having a lot of trouble getting my php querys re-written to any sort of seo friendly url.

I want to get

http://example.com/provider_list/Dublin.html from the url below

http://example.com/provider_list.php?**locationName=Dublin**&checkIn_Date=09%2F07%2F2012&checkOut_Date=10%2F07%2F2012&extratype=1&noofextra=1&x=50&y=21

And the same for all other locations

e.g.

provider_list/Wexford.html

So if the query includes the "locationName=ANYLOCATION" it would re write it to this...

It shouldn't matter what the values are for the other names in the query string ...

Is this possible through .htacess?

All help gratefully recieved..

Comment: Just confirming :- so if url is http://example.com/provider_list.php?locationName=Dublin its must be REDIRECTED to http://example.com/provider_list/Dublin.html, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule provider_list/(\w+).html /locationName=$1&checkIn_Date=09%2F07%2F2012&checkOut_Date=10%2F07%2F2012&extratype=1&noofextra=1&x=50&y=21 [L]
```

But this is not elegant solution with such long query string, is it necessary?

Comment: So does checkInDate and all the other parameters after locationName in the query string have to equal those exact values ? I wish for this string to be rewritted to that URL regardless of the values of the parameters except locationName..

Comment: Sorry on the string question, yes .. This is how it is called from the links...Many thanks